# Android tflite convert output location to bounding box on screen

Tags: android, tensorflow, kotlin

I'm trying to convert my tflite output location to position that user can see on screen.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong but the tflite supposed to give me the location (left,right,top,bottom) between 0 and 1. but it give the output between 320 and 320 (this my model input).

**this is my image analyzer class:(It's live detection and I use CameraX)**

```
// Initializing the jaw detection model
private val jawDetectionModel = JawDetection.newInstance(context)

val imageProcessor = ImageProcessor.Builder()
        .add(ResizeWithCropOrPadOp(320, 320))
        .add(ResizeOp(320, 320, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR))
        .add(NormalizeOp(0f, 1f))
        .build()

    // Convert Image to Bitmap then to TensorImage
    val tfImage = TensorImage.fromBitmap(imageProxy.convertImageProxyToBitmap(context))

    // Process the image using the trained model, sort and pick out the top results
    val outputs = jawDetectionModel.process(imageProcessor.process(tfImage))
        .detectionResultList.take(MaxResultDisplay)

    val left = outputs.first().locationAsRectF.left 
    val top = outputs.first().locationAsRectF.top 
    val right = outputs.first().locationAsRectF.right 
    val bottom = outputs.first().locationAsRectF.bottom
```

**and this for convert image proxy to bitmap:**

```
    @SuppressLint("UnsafeExperimentalUsageError")
fun ImageProxy.convertImageProxyToBitmap(context: Context): Bitmap? {
    val yuvToRgbConverter = YuvToRgbConverter(context)

    val image = this.image ?: return null

    // Initialise Buffer
    if (!::bitmapBuffer.isInitialized) {
        rotationMatrix = Matrix()
        rotationMatrix.postRotate(this.imageInfo.rotationDegrees.toFloat())
        bitmapBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(
            this.width, this.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        )
    }

    // Pass image to an image analyser
    yuvToRgbConverter.yuvToRgb(image, bitmapBuffer)

    // Create the Bitmap in the correct orientation
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(
        bitmapBuffer,
        0,
        0,
        bitmapBuffer.width,
        bitmapBuffer.height,
        rotationMatrix,
        false
    )

}
```